# Java how to sort a list of array: List<Object[]>

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Java how to sort a list of array: `List<String[]>`

```
List<String[]> rows=new ArrayList<String[]>();

Collections.sort(rows);
```

`Collections.sort(rows)` gives me the following errors:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<String[]>). 
The inferred type String[] is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Comment: How do you want to sort it? According to what? Do you want the array to be sorted as well?

Comment: Java does not implement array comparison by default. With what criterion do you wish your arrays to be sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this is not a standard sort according to the natural order of the objects, because there is no natural order of arrays.

You might be looking for [`Collections.sort(rows,comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), where `comparator` is your custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) objects, that tells you "which array is bigger".

The implementation of the `Comparator` is obviously dependent on the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a comparator.

```
class StringArrayComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {

    public int compare(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
        // Conditions here.
    }
}
```

Then plug it into the Collections call:

```
Collections.sort(rows, new StringArrayComparator());
```

This will sort the `String[]` list according to the criteria in the comparator.